# Make categories on Highcharts stay

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

Every time I put data into my Highcharts chart, the categories along the x & y axis are dynamic and adjust based on the data. I want the categories to remain the same, I want: categories: ['1', '10', '100', '1000', '10000'] along both axis.

Does anybody know how to make them stay the same regardless of the data in-putted?

[image]

This is my chart, but I want the numbers along the bottom and the left-hand side to display 1, 10, 100, 1000, 1000'

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {


         function newRandomColor() {
         var color = [];
         color.push((Math.random() * 255).toFixed());
         color.push((Math.random() * 255).toFixed());
         color.push((Math.random() * 255).toFixed());
         color.push((Math.random()).toFixed(2));
         var text = 'rgba(' + color.join(',') + ')';
         console.log(text);
         return text;
         }

         function newRandomData(n) {
         // generate an array of random data
         var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

         for (i = -1 * n; i <= 0; i++) {
            var color = newRandomColor();
            data.push({
                y:Math.random() * 90 + 60,
                color: color,
                fillColor: color
                      });
         }
         return data;

         }



                 $('#chart5').highcharts({
                     chart: {
                         type: 'scatter',
                         marginRight: 130,
                         marginBottom: 35
                     },
                     title: {
                         text: 'Average vs Max Alarm Rates',
                         x: -20 //center
                     },

                     subtitle: {
                         text: '',
                         x: -20
                     },

                     xAxis: {

                         title: {
                             text: 'Peak alarm rate/10 mins'
                         },
                         plotLines: [{
                             value: 0,
                             width: 1,
                             color: '#b51f2b'
                         }]
                     },
                     yAxis: {

                         title: {
                             text: 'Average alarm rate/10 mins'
                         },
                         plotLines: [{
                             value: 0,
                             width: 1,
                             color: '#b51f2b'
                         }]
                     },
                     tooltip: {
                         valueSuffix: ' alarms'
                     },
                     legend: {
                         layout: 'vertical',
                         align: 'right',
                         verticalAlign: 'top',
                         x: -10,
                         y: 100,
                         borderWidth: 0
                     },
                     series: [{
          color: 'green',
                         name: 'Alarms',

            data: newRandomData(40)

                     }]

                 }, function(chart) { // on complete

         chart.renderer.image('images/alarmrategrid.png', 57, 41, 635, 248)
         .add();   

         });
         });



      </script>
```

I tried adding the categories, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you show the code for the chart? generally you can customize the categories along each axis.

Comment: @SoftwareGuy have done, cheers :)

Comment: well, you would probably know that but you are using the scatter chart and it does not have the categories option available. See: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter - Perhaps try another chart type if applicable?

Comment: also, consider looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451582/possible-to-use-highcharts-scatter-plot-with-categories

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions / tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Answer (score 0):

You can just set your min and max for each axis:

http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/314/

```
 categories: ['1', '10', '100', '1000', '10000'],
        min:0,
        max:4,
        tickmarkPlacement:'on',
```